# Consistency Combo box ( two comboboxes )

Tags: php, javascript, combobox, consistency

I have two combo boxes in my program...

look like this -->

---

### box1

- 1   -
- 2   -
- 3   -
- 4   -
- 5   -

---

---

### box2

- 1   -
- 2   -
- 3   -
- 4   -
- 5   -

How can i do it work in this solution ?

such as ...  in box1 i'm selected '1' ..... and then i'm open a box2 i won't see the list was i selected on box1.

Have a solution to do it please ?

( i'm using PHP and JavaScipt )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is when you select an item on box1 then box2 appears.

If this is the case you have to use javascript and if possible jquery to simplify the work.

Just create an [on change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for box1 and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) box2 when something happens

Hope this helps